# Beginner: "HCURSOR" to "const char*" cast, using an IF statement to detect a change in the cursor icon

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, casting

- **Background**

This is C/C++ code that detects when the cursor icon changes, and passes the pointer value of the cursor's current image to printf.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void CursorIcon()
{
  CURSORINFO ci = { sizeof(ci) };
  GetCursorInfo(&ci);
  printf("handle = %p\n", ci.hCursor);
}

int main(){
  CursorIcon();
}
```

As an example: when the cursor is using the default arrow image, printf says the pointer value is "0000000000010005".

- **Problem**
  After finding the above value, I wanted to use it in an if statement after ***printf*** in the ***CursorIcon()*** function as detailed below

  ```
  if(ci.hCursor=="0000000000010005"){
   printf("This is an arrow mouse icon!");
  ```

  However, I'm given this error "***comparison between distinct pointer types 'HCURSOR {aka HICON__*}' and 'const char*' lacks a cast [-fpermissive]**"
- **Attempted Solutions**

  1. When using '0000000000010005' (or 0000000000010005 ) in the if statement instead, the compiler says ***"ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]"***
  2. So I attempted to read up on 'Casts', and I tried my hardest to turn the IF statement into what I believed was correct casting for the original error given, trying my attempt of a static cast, which was seemingly incorrect (and also adding `#include <iostream>`):I tried                 `if(ci.hCursor==(HCURSOR)0000000000010005)` and `if(ci.hCursor==static_cast<HCURSOR>0000000000010005)`

Now, I'm here with a small headache and a bit of confusion on where to look next to solve this problem.

Comment: That's not how to detect the arrow icon. Use `LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW)` to obtain a handle to the arrow icon. You can then compare the two handles.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into how to compare handles, I might need to stick to my book though because this little project is getting out-of-hand seemingly.

Comment: The handles are just pointers, compare them as-is: `HCURSOR hArrow; ... hArrow  = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW); ... if (ci.hCursor == hArrow) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the number printed by %p is implementation specific. The Microsoft implementation prints a 0 padded [hexadecimal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). If you want to use it in your code you must prefix it with 0x and add a cast. For 0000000000010005 you would use `if (cursorhandle == (HCURSOR) 0x010005) ...`.

As pointed out in the comments, hardcoding this number is not the correct approach because the standard cursor handle values are not documented to be stable. You should get the cursor handle by calling `LoadCursor`:

```
HCURSOR hArrow = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
if (ci.hCursor == hArrow) printf("This is the standard arrow cursor\n");
```